# Is it possible to detect the ABI at runtime from within the Android VM?

Tags: android, android-ndk, abi

I need to be able to detect in Java the ABI (armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86 or mips) of a device at runtime. Is this possible ?

Comment: You should be able to get that by reading [the `CPU_ABI` property](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#CPU_ABI).

Comment: That looks like the job. Thanks. Do you want to put that up as the answer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Build` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#CPU_ABI) has a member named `CPU_ABI`, corresponding to the `ro.product.cpu.abi` system property. It should give you what you are looking for.

You could use regular expressions to match `CPU_ABI` against anything that contains "arm", "x86" or "mips" to cover all/most variants of each CPU type.

Answer (score 6):

`Build.CPU_ABI` is now deprecated.

Starting from API 21 You should use instead `Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS`.

`Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS` is an ordered list of ABIs supported by this device. The most preferred ABI is the first element in the list.